# ant debug is not working

Tags: ant

I have downloaded "**Ant**" to D:Windows folder.set the **ANT_HOME** environment variable as "D:\Windows\apache-ant-1.7.0".I have added it as both syatem variable and user variable. But when i open the command prompt and run the command "*ant -versions*" it is displaying error message as "**ant is not recoganised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file**".Is there any error in installing Ant?Do i need to add **bin** to ANT_HOME?Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add like this

Add ANT_HOME environment variable

```
ANT_HOME = "D:\Windows\apache-ant-1.7.0"
```

edit environment PATH variable to %ANT_HOME%/bin folder

```
PATH = ...maybe-other-entries...;%ANT_HOME%\bin;...maybe-other-entries...
```

Answer (score 0):

ANT_HOME - used for detect what of many location should be used by environment

To use ant from command line you have set PATH variable. Edit existing one (system for example) and append to the end with `;` separator location of ant.

BTW since ANT_HOME is already set you can use extended syntax for set PATH:

```
PATH=c:\windows......;%ANT_HOME%
```